# actionlib client, How to get goal ID?

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have simple action client and server. What I want to do is to get goal ID in action client.

When I send a goal to action server, it generates a goal ID and publishes all status and feedback messages with this unique goal ID. How can I get this corresponding goal ID in action client?

I want to track status of goals from `/action_server/status` topic, not from ActionClient's `getState()` method. So to be able to find my goal from status list array in `/status` topic, I need to know the generated goal ID.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265723/actionlib-client,-how-to-get-goal-id?/) by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-07-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agutenkunst](https://answers.ros.org/users/30729/agutenkunst/) on 2017-07-08**:
You want to look from "outside" into the client<->server connection? So both client and server are not written by you?

**Comment by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on 2017-07-10**:
Not exactly. Client is written by me, however I want to track the status of the goal from /status topic. Not using GoalHandle. So I need goal ID in client side.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, goal ID is stored in client side but not exposed to public.

In GoalHandle, actionlib uses goal ID to cancel a goal. But list_handle_ is private therefore you cannot get goal ID over it. You can check https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/indigo-devel/include/actionlib/client/client_goal_handle_imp.h#L245

Even tough I suggest tracking a goal status over GoalHandle, if you need it, maybe you can fork and change actionlib source accordingly. Or post an issue to upstream repo, if there is no appearent reason preventing it, authors may add a public member function like getGoalID() to ClientGoalHandle class (or you can post a PR).

@Dirk Thomas or @tfoote may help at this point.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on 2017-07-11**:
Thanks for the answer. In fact I do not want to alter the source code of actionlib to get updates regularly. Still looking for a better option.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Simple Action Client is designed to be a *simple* example of how to write an action client. If you'd like to have more functionality I'd recommend either extending it or using the core ActionClient and implementing your desired extended behavior.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on 2017-07-11**:
Thanks for the answer, but I could not find any member which I can retrieve goal_id from.`ActionClient` and `ClientGoalHandle` do not seem to provide any way to get goal_id.Seems like I need to change src of GoalHandle to reach `list_handle_.getElem()->getActionGoal()->goal_id.id`. Any clue on this?